# How to extract only value "2"?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

```
magic_number = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("people_alt")')

magic_number = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("people_alt")').text

magic_number = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("people_alt")').next_sibling
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code as text and an url it is not that easy, so question needs improvement. Selecting more specific should work:

```
soup.select_one('.material-icons:-soup-contains("people_alt")').next_sibling.strip()
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<span>
<span class="material-icons">people_alt</span>
2
</span>

'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('.material-icons:-soup-contains("people_alt")').next_sibling.strip()
```

##### Output

```
2
```